# How do you extract parameters from a url that only contain slash using python?

Tags: python, url, python-3.6, urllib, urlparse

I have an url "http://example.com/title/hello/users/123/example-1". I would like to extract the information Title: "hello", users": "123" as well as "example-1". How can i use urllib to extract these info? I do not want to use regex for this.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = 'http://example.com/title/hello/users/123/example-1'
print(urlparse(url))

# How do i extract the parameters in the path below?
# ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='example.com', path='/title/hello/users/123/example-1', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried urlparse but all i got in return is just "/title/hello/users/123/example-1".

Comment: Please post your code!

Comment: I don't really have a working code right now.

Comment: I could try to get by with the split("/") function but is there a python lib that automatically does the extraction?

Comment: The idea is that you post your non-working code, so we can help fixing it.

Comment: ok i made an edit to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

parsed = urlparse('http://example.com/title/hello/users/123/example-1')
parsed = parsed.path.split("/")
```

Urlparse returns a parsed object. We can use the path of this parser object and split it by "/". Here is the result :

```
['', 'title', 'hello', 'users', '123', 'example-1']
```